# C# XPath with Html Agility Pack returning null

Tags: c#, xpath, twitter, html-agility-pack

I'm trying to parse tweets from my Twitter Timeline with XPath in C#. I'm getting the HTML from `http://www.twitter.com/username/`. How can I parse this HTML code into C# object list? I'm not very familiar with the Twitter API.

Currently I'm using the following code to parse:

```
var tweets = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[contains(@class, 'js-stream-tweet')]");
```

But I don't think thats the best way to parse whole tweet object (element and children). It's returning `null`.

Thank you.

Comment: How you are fetching html content, can you provide code?

Comment: @RubenVardanyanvar I don't think that there is the problem. But maybe I'm wrong. `Webget = new HtmlWeb();
    var doc = Webget.Load("http://www.twitter.com/janchalupa/");
    var tweets = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[contains(@class, 'js-stream-tweet')]");`

Comment: The problem is there :) see the answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set `UserAgent` for the `HtmlWeb`. Twitter returns different html content according to `UserAgent`

```
Webget.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.81 Safari/537.36";
```

Comment: Great, that helped! Thank you.